# How can I draw a 3D CAD in browser using webgl with nodes and elements?

Tags: three.js, webgl, cad

I want to visualize it in a browser either using three.js or any other library. Data is available in the following format from ABAQUS.

Node has in the form of [posX, posY, posZ].
Element has data in the form of [Node1, Node2 ...... Node8]

```
structure_details = {
            "nodes": [{
                "number": 1,
                /* [posX, posY, posZ] */
                "position": [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
            },{
                "number": 2,
                "position": [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
            },{
                "number": 3,
                "position": [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
            },{
                "number": 4,
                "position": [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
            }
            ...],
            "elements": [{
                "number": 1,
                "type": "octahedral",
                "nodes": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            }
            ...]
        }
```

Comment: You need to export your model in a different format that Three natively supports, like OBJ or STL. Otherwise you'll have to write your own loader to convert it into Three.js data, which is too broad to answer in this question.

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay for answering but I don't think I would have access to standard OBJ or STL files and would require a way to get CAD using this data only in webgl/three.js.

Comment: I do have access to .odb from ABAQUS which supposedly does not store information related to normals to each surface element. Other option would be to process this data to calculate all required data and form a JSONloader file which can directly be used in three.js library.